# UISearchBar appearance not set on second load

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, appearance

I am trying to modify the background color of the text field / label in the search bar using appearance.
I'm using UISearchController that's added to iOS 8.
From my view controller -viewDidLoad, I set the appearance of the search bar like this.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

It works fine on the first load, but interestingly, if I close the viewController and then reopen it, it won't apply this appearance again. The text field falls back to the default background color which is white.

Not sure what I'm missing. Can someone please help me? Could it be an iOS 8 bug?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.. but this may help you.Please try this
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

Comment: Please always give your answer in proper formatting.